# Display Notepad++ file search results in realtime?

Tags: search, notepad++

Is there a way to display Notepad++ file search results as they are found, rather than all at once when the search is completed? When searching through large directories, it would be nice to be able stop the search once I have found what I am looking for.

I am using Notepad++ 6.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

No , there is not! You can only cancel the search to see search result  or wait for it to finish!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try other editor SynWrite, it has real time showing of file results in its Find Results tab.